# Using webpage link as in image element but not responding

Tags: javascript, html

So I am new to HTML. I have a webpage that contains only a picture in its background; with each refresh, a new image is loaded. However, I want to use that webpage link as in the Image element so anyone can use that image in their webpage, I know `< iframe >` tag can be done for this task but I can not use it, due to some reason.
some what similar to this :http://placeimg.com/640/480/people

```
 <body id="testing" onLoad="randompicture()">
            <script>
     function randompicture(){
     const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
     const path='images/image' +i+ '.png';
     console.log(path)
    document.getElementById("testing").setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + path +");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 388px 388px");
               }
       
            </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: Are you asking why you can't have `<img src="url-to-an-html-document">`?

Comment: yes, I am trying to achieve this. like we can use this page URL http://placeimg.com/640/480/people in our image src. I want to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://placeimg.com/640/480/people` is a URL to an image.

Which image you get is determined by server-side code.

It is not an HTML document. It is not done with client-side JS.

You cannot use an HTML document as the source URL for an `img` element or background image.

Comment: So, do I have to use node js for this

Comment: To reproduce what placeimg does, you need to use server side code. Node.js is a perfectly good runtime for server side code if you want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, I used the flask and it work.  here is the link: https://github.com/samadpls/Islamic-qoutes